# Should adding static_assert ever cause a program to stop having errors?

Tags: c++

.I have a program that fails to compile on clang. When I added static_assert's to try to narrow down the problem, the program compiled fine. Take the asserts out, it fails again. Is this a clang bug? In particular, does this violate §7.0.4 "If the value of the expression when so converted is true, the declaration has no effect."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename function_t, typename...Args>
typename std::result_of<function_t(Args...)>::type
memoize(function_t f, Args&&...a) {
    static std::map<std::tuple<function_t,Args...>, typename std::result_of<function_t(Args...)>::type> computed;
    std::tuple<function_t,Args...> arg_tuple = std::make_tuple(*f,a...);
    auto search = computed.find(arg_tuple);
    if (search != computed.end()) {
        return search->second;
    } else {
        return computed[arg_tuple] = f(a...);
    }
}

long long fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    // static_assert(std::is_same<std::result_of<decltype(&fibonacci)(int)>::type,long long>::value,"Type mismatch!\n");
    return memoize<decltype(&fibonacci),int>(fibonacci,n-1)
         + memoize<decltype(&fibonacci),int>(fibonacci,n-2);
}

int main() {
    int val = 50;
    // static_assert(std::is_same<std::result_of<decltype(&fibonacci)(int)>::type,long long>::value,"Type Mismatch!\n");
    std::cout << "fibonacci(" << val <<") = " << memoize<decltype(&fibonacci), int>(fibonacci,std::move(val)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why is your memoizing function specialized on both the type of the function to memoize and the arguments this functions receives, instead of on the function memoized?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I needed some way to get the types of the arguments. This seemed like a straightforward method.

Comment: It seems the magic is `std::result_of<decltype(&fibonacci)(int)>::type`. If you remove the `static_assert`s but just keep the `result_of`, then it compiles. Also, if you remove `,int` from the template list, it compiles. Going a step further, `memoize(fibonacci,n-1)` works just fine, too. However, I'm unsure of why these things work, and don't have time to investigate more.

Comment: Using `-fsanitize=undefined` gave me an interesting runtime error on this code. That may help you dig further.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: What flags are you using? I didn't get any runtime error -fsanitize .

Comment: Here is a [live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db4975814f324e6) I try to use an [online evaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652386/1708801) when I can.